# Which lattices have non-trivial linear representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lattice-theory, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a a bounded lattice $L$. We might ask: does there exist a non-trivial linear representation of $L$, i.e. a lattice homomorphism $\rho: L \to \text{Sp}(V)$, where $V$ is a non-zero finite dimensional vector space, and $\text{Sp}(V)$ is the lattice of subspaces of $V$, and we require $\rho(0) = \{ 0\}$ and $\rho(1) = V$.

One simple necessary condition is the existence of a function $d: L \to \mathbb{N}$, satisfying:

- $d(0) = 0$, and $d(1) = n > 0$
- $d(a) \leq d(b)$ whenever $a \leq b$
- $d(a) + d(b) = d(a\lor b) + d(a\land b)$

Is the existence of such a $d$ sufficient?

I've encountered various related results about *faithful* representations (i.e. sublattices of $\text{Sp}(V)$). E.g. those lattices need to be modular and arguesian. However, for representations that are not required to be faithful, we might get away with non-modularity for example, by just quotienting out the non-modular part of the lattice (e.g. collapsing the vertical edge in the non-modular pentagon $N_5$). I haven't found any literature on what sort of conditions might remain if we don't require faithfulness. Are there any known results regarding this?

Comment: How unfaithful are you ready to be? Is, for example, something like $L\twoheadrightarrow\{0<1\}\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Sp}(V)$ OK?

Comment: It would be OK, but having a lattice homomorphism onto $\{0 < 1\}$ seems quite far from being a necessary condition, even though it's sufficient.

Comment: I wonder whether every lattice $L$ has a unique modular quotient $L^{\text{mod}}$ through which any map to a modular lattice factors?

Comment: According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55515/additive-functions-on-a-lattice , the answer is yes. So we are reduced to answering your question for $L^{\text{mod}}$.

Comment: A good test case would be to ask if a non-Desarguean projective plane has such a representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Desarguesian_plane

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to David E Speyer for the helpful pointers.

I can now answer the first question (is the existence of the function $d$ sufficient?) in the negative.

A function $d$ with the given properties is an *isotone valuation* as defined in point 6, Chapter V of Birkhoff's "Lattice theory". As in Theorem 9 in the same chapter, we can take a quotient of the lattice, on which the induced $d$ is strictly increasing (called a *metric lattice* in Birkhoff), and which is therefore a modular lattice.

So the existence of such a $d$ (modulo some finiteness condition) is equivalent to having a non-trivial modular quotient.

Based on this, we might suspect that the existence of such a $d$ is not sufficient to have a non-trivial linear representation, since sublattices of $\text{Sp}(V)$ have further properties (e.g. being [arguesian](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Arguesian_lattice)).

As a concrete counter-example, we can take the incidence lattice $L$ of a finite [non-Desarguesian projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Desarguesian_plane). Such an $L$ is modular (the function $d$ can be taken to be $d(point) = 1$, $d(line) = 2$), non-arguesean, and as it turns out also *simple* (i.e. without any smaller non-trivial quotients). It therefore cannot have a non-trivial arguesean quotient.

The fact that such a lattice $L$ is simple follows from Corollary 1 in Chapter V of Birkhoff:

> A modular lattice of finite length is ‘‘simple’’ (i.e., without
> proper congruence relations) if and only if all its prime quotients are projective.

I believe the fact that there's a line passing through any pair of points is sufficient in this case to show that all prime quotients are projective.

*Birkhoff, Garrett*, Lattice theory, New York: American Mathematical Society (AMS). v, 155 p. (1940). [ZBL0063.00402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.00402).